# How to import with PYTHONPATH?

Tags: airflow, python-import

I use importlib to import the necessary lib to airflow:

```
task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='my_task_1',
    python_callable=my_python_script,
    op_kwargs={
        'script_path': f'./{kafka_folder}/consumer_app.py'
    },
    dag=dag
)


def my_python_script(script_path):
    import importlib.util
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", script_path)
    script = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(script)

    if script.success:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

How to import the python file using PYTHONPATH, if I need the result of execution for task in DAG? The imported module has cascade dependencies (other related modules) inside.